# Camel- Quarkus: No bean could be found in the registry for: servlet of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestApiConsumerFactory

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I'm trying to get a simple Quarkus/Camel app going, and have hit a snag. I just keep getting the same error:

`No bean could be found in the registry for: servlet of type: org.apache.camel.spi.RestApiConsumerFactory`

Googling comes up pretty sparce, unsure where to go from here.

Camel dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>

            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>

            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-rest</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>

            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-direct</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>

            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jackson</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>

            <artifactId>camel-quarkus-mock</artifactId>

        </dependency>
```

Route Setup

```java
public class RestRoute extends RouteBuilder {


    @Override

    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration()

        .component("servlet")

        .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)

        .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")

        .apiContextPath("/api-doc")

        .apiProperty("api.title", "REST API").apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")

        .apiProperty("cors", "true");

        

        rest("/")

                .consumes("application/json")

                .produces("application/json")

                .get()

                .outType(TestObj.class)

                .to("direct:getTestObj");

        

        from("direct:getTestObj")

            .transform()

            .constant(

                TestObj.builder().fieldOne("Hello").fieldTwo("World").build()

            );

    }

}
```

When `.component("servlet")` is removed, I get the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath (such as the camel-openapi-java component)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java have different app and web servers like netty , jetty tomcat , glassfish etc. spring use tomcat in default and tomcat is a servlet implementation therefore spring has servlet classes , quarkus not use tomcat therefore quarkus dont have servlet , quarkus use vert.x and in background vert.x use netty. u must remove explicity component definition just delete it

```
 .component("servlet")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but raises another error, updated the question with it

Comment: removes thats it will be work 

        .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")

        .apiContextPath("/api-doc")

        .apiProperty("api.title", "REST API").apiProperty("api.version", "1.0")

        .apiProperty("cors", "true");

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Happen to know if there is a replacement for these methods, or if there is a way to get them to work?

Comment: <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-quarkus-openapi-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

this dependency can solve this new problem , my suggestion we should build as a simple way when starting

Answer (score 0):

You should use `platform-http` as the component in Quarkus. However Camel should auto-detect this by default, so you can remove the `.component("servlet")` in your code, and use the out of the box setting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but raises another error, updated the question with it